# Add custom domain on Azure without application restart?

Tags: domains, iis, azure

Few months ago Azure started restarting applications when change occurs in custom domains. This behavior is, of course, quite bothersome as, aside of unnecessary restarts, startup on Azure can't exactly be called swift. In my case I have two unrelated systems where few dozen domains point to single azure application with fixed IP address so restarts have negative influence on my mailbox.

I get same behavior in portal.azure.com and via powershell (Set-AzureWebsite -HostNames ...) for top and sub domains, but wildcards are not causing restarts.

Is there some trick to get around this "feature"? Perhaps there is some magic hidden in powershell interface?

Answer (score 1):

follow the indications in this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60743863/azure-web-app-random-restart-can-anyone-expand-on-this-recommendation, and added the

```
WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG
```

configuration with value 1 to the app service in the Azure portal. This is the only way so far to prevent the app service from restarting after adding /removing custom domain bindings.

[image]

There might be side effect though. After adding this setting, users started to see this warning in their logs:

```
Level:Warning
Message:Connection processing ended abnormally.
SourceContext:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
Exception:
Message:The connection was aborted
StackTrace:   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
```